# Let $A, B, C$ be ideals in a Dedekind domain $R$. Showing $A \cap (B+C) = (A \cap B) + (A \cap C)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, dedekind-domain

Let $A, B, C$ be Ideals in a Dedekind domain $R$. I want to show that $A \cap (B+C) = (A \cap B) + (A \cap C)$, where $(A \cap B) + (A \cap C) \subset A \cap (B+C)$ is obviously true. Now I would like to show the opposite, but I don't really know how I should apply the characteristics of the Dedekind domain and where to start from here... As far as my script goes, I know that each ideal is a product of prime/maximal ideals and (to prove said product) we just introduced the fractional ideals

Comment: If any one of $A, B, C$ is the zero ideal, then the formula is true for trivial reasons. Any nonzero ideal in $R$ is a product of powers of distinct maximal ideals of $R$, and this factorization is unique up to rearrangement of the factors. Using this, if $A, B$ are nonzero ideals of $R$, you should try to prove a formula for the ideals $A \cap B, A+B$ in terms of the factorizations of $A$ and $B$. Proving your claimed formula then becomes straightforward.

Comment: A fact from lattice theory that might help is that the ideal lattice of a ring is distributive if and only if the following condition holds for all ideals $A,B,C$: if $A\cap C=B\cap C$ and $A+C=B+C$, then $A=B$.

If you can prove $(I\cap J)(I+J)=IJ$ for any ideals $I,J$ in a Dedekind domain, then your desired result follows from this characterization of distributivity.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Your tip was really helpful and I managed to solve it! I will probably add an answer (some details) underneath my question, so thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: @NamelessGuy that's great, I'm glad to hear it!